# Redirect a domain from Joomla 1.5.11 to Wordpress on different domain

Tags: joomla1.5

I have a question, I built a website for a client with a new domain (www.domain1.com) and new hosting. They have an old website with a different domain (www.domain2.com). The client requests that if someone clicks on www.domain2.com, that would take them to www.domain1.com. I built the website using WordPress, and the old website is built using Joomla 1.5.11 which doesn't have the option to use redirect under the Components option. I don't have any experience in Joomla 1.5.11 which is pretty old. Thanks in advance for looking into this for me.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want the domain to be redirected?
You can set up a `301` permanent wildcard redirect on your domain2.com to point to domain1.com.
Setting this up will also depend on the type of host you're using.

Also, you can set up an index.php file at the root of domain2.com to redirect:

```
<?php
    header("Location: domain1.com");
?>
```

The problem with the above script is that you won't be able to do a wildcard redirect! But it can work with any Joomla! link, as Joomla's entrypoint is always set to index.php.

If none of the above is feasible for you, try adding more details about what you actually want to do.